# NodeJS Express hosted GWT compiled application not rendering CSS

Tags: css, node.js, gwt, express, url-mapping

I have this GWT application that I placed within NodeJS/Express. The site loads, however, the CSS is not applied. When I open the HTML file separately in the browser, however, it does render the CSS correctly.

Any idea why this happen? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Server: NodeJS with Express

Client: Web app - Compiled with GWT

Comment: I think you should provide, a little more information... WE ARE NOT GODS TO KNOW EVERYTHING!

Comment: @alFReDNSH Easy, sorry if my question lacks detail. I was hoping that someone have experienced hosting a GWT-compiled web app into Nodejs with Express.

Comment: BTW, what information are you looking for? I mean, the server is NodeJS with Express on it. Do you mean debug info? If so, I don't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base URL is [different](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleWebToolkit/2009-08/msg01010.html) when running locally versus running on the domain [hosted by nodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127131/). Try using an [absolute path](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion) or adding an [errorHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329831/) to find the base URL.